# Hadoop: Query Parquet with Pig for TPC-H Benchmark

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform, parquet

I'm trying to run the TPC-H Benchmark (www.tpc.org) on Hadoop with Hortonworks Data Platform (2.3.2). Therefor I want to use Pig (Version 0.15) to query data in Parquet file format and benchmark that. I´ve created 2 GB of data in parquet file format using tpch-gen. Furthermore I´ve downloaded a pig-parquet-bundle to read the parquet file using the ParquetLoader. I'm using the following Pig script to query it:

```
REGISTER /opt/parquet-pig-bundle-1.8.1.jar;

lineitem = LOAD '$input/lineitem' 
using org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader AS (orderkey:long, partkey:long, suppkey:long,
linenumber:long, quantity:double, extendedprice:double, discount:double, tax:double, returnflag:chararray, linestatus:chararray,
shipdate:chararray, commitdate:chararray, receiptdate:chararray, shipinstruct:chararray, shipmode:chararray, comment:chararray);

SubLineItems = FILTER lineitem BY shipdate <= '1998-09-16';

SubLine = FOREACH SubLineItems GENERATE returnflag, linestatus, quantity, extendedprice, extendedprice*(1-discount) AS disc_price, extendedprice*(1-discount)*(1+tax) AS charge, discount;

STORE SubLine INTO '$output/Q1_out' USING org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetStorer();
```

When i execute this query I get the following error:

> > 2016-01-28 15:57:23,974 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the
> >     script: FILTER 
> >     2016-01-28 15:57:24,035 [main] INFO 
> >     org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not
> >     set... will not generate code. 2016-01-28 15:57:24,098 [main] INFO 
> >     org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer -
> >     {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator,
> >     GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter,
> >     MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer,
> >     PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter,
> >     SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]} 2016-01-28 15:57:24,155 [main]
> >     INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor -
> >     Columns pruned for lineitem: $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $9, $11,
> >     $12, $13, $14, $15 2016-01-28 15:57:24,160 [main] ERROR
> >     org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2000: Error processing rule
> >     ColumnMapKeyPrune. Try -t ColumnMapKeyPrune Details at logfile:
> >     /root/D2F-Bench/bin/pig_1453996639031.log

When I'm using the mentioned -t ColumnMapKeyPrune the query is executing without that error but it takes about 1 hour which is way too long.

I noticed that the error just appears when I use a "FOREACH" in the Pig query, when I delete the line that contains the FOREACH the error is not appearing. Furthermore I´ve already tried to query avro file format with the same pig script (just changed the using ... line) and that was working fine.

Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

p.s. the pig stack trace gives the following information:

> > ERROR 2000: Error processing rule ColumnMapKeyPrune. Try -t ColumnMapKeyPrune
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 2000: Error
>   processing rule ColumnMapKeyPrune. Try -t ColumnMapKeyPrune   at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.optimizer.PlanOptimizer.optimize(PlanOptimizer.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan.optimize(LogicalPlan.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1373)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1364)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:415)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)     at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:502)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader.getSchemaFromRequiredFieldList(ParquetLoader.java:364)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader.pushProjection(ParquetLoader.java:346)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor.visit(ColumnPruneVisitor.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.accept(LOLoad.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
>     at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)    at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnMapKeyPrune$ColumnMapKeyPruneTransformer.transform(ColumnMapKeyPrune.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.optimizer.PlanOptimizer.optimize(PlanOptimizer.java:110)
>
> ## ... 17 more

Comment: Followers of [hortonworks] and [hortonworks-data-platform] may be interested in [a Meta question proposing to move all questions from one to the other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315789).

Comment: have you tried dump just after loading the file, is it working ?